# Rotate a geometry in a way that it would be parallel to a specific line

Tags: qt, vector, rotation, qt3d

I have a benchmark `line` like this:

```
QVector3D line = QVector3D(38.0572, 29.2247, 35.3996);
```

---

I create a cone with Qt3D like this:

```
Qt3DCore::QEntity *newEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();

Qt3DExtras::QConeMesh *mesh = new Qt3DExtras::QConeMesh();
mesh->setTopRadius(0.2);
mesh->setBottomRadius(1.0);
mesh->setLength(2.0);
for(int i = 0; i < mesh->geometry()->attributes().size(); ++i) {
    mesh->geometry()->attributes().at(i)->buffer()->setSyncData(true);
}

newEntity->addComponent(mesh);
```

As far as I check, the default cone axis is `QVector3D(0, 1, 0)`:

[image: Cone]

---

Now I want to rotate/transform my cone in a way that my cone axis is parallel to my benchmark `line`. It can be done with `Qt3DCore::QTransform`:

```
// ... previous code lines

Qt3DCore::QTransform *transform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();
transform->setRotationX(?);
transform->setRotationY(?);
transform->setRotationZ(?);
transform->setRotation(?);
transform->setTranslation(?);
transform->setMatrix(?);

newEntity->addComponent(transform);
```

I don't know how to assemble my transformation component in a way that my cone axis would be parallel to the benchmark `line`.

---

I have studied these, but no luck so far:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis

Comment: Your `line` starts in the origin `(0, 0, 0)` I assume? Maybe you could divide the line's direction vector by 29.2247 to obtain a direction vector that looks like this: (x, 1, y). Then you could (more easily than before) solve the equation system, where you put `cone_axis * R_x * R_y * R_z = line`. I'm actually not sure whether this is solvable analytically but you could try [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to solve it. Maybe also post your question to [maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/), as this is not really an issue of Qt3d but maths in general.

Comment: @FlorianBlume That's right. It's more of a math problem.

Comment: Maybe this can help as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542801/rotate-3d-coordinate-system-such-that-z-axis-is-parallel-to-a-given-vector.

Comment: @FlorianBlume Wow! That's great. Thanks :)

Comment: I hope it helps you to solve your question! If you find an answer post it, I'm intrigued myself ;)

Comment: @FlorianBlume Sure! I'll post my solution if I finally solve it ☺

Comment: @FlorianBlume The problem is solved by [your suggested method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/543538/197913). I posted the answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @FlorianBlume and his suggested [q & a](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/543538/197913), the problem got solved. Here is the code for transformation matrix:

```
Qt3DCore::QEntity *newEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();

Qt3DExtras::QConeMesh *mesh = new Qt3DExtras::QConeMesh();
mesh->setTopRadius(0.2);
mesh->setBottomRadius(1.0);
mesh->setLength(2.0);
for(int i = 0; i < mesh->geometry()->attributes().size(); ++i) {
    mesh->geometry()->attributes().at(i)->buffer()->setSyncData(true);
}

newEntity->addComponent(mesh);

/* 
 * Now transform the cone to change its default axis:
 */

QVector3D k = QVector3D(0, 1, 0);   // Current cone axis
QVector3D n = QVector3D(38.0572, 29.2247, 35.3996); // To-be cone axis
n *= -1; // Inverse cone direction
n.normalize();
float teta = qAcos(QVector3D::dotProduct( k, n ));
QVector3D b = QVector3D::crossProduct( k , n );
b.normalize();

float q0 = qCos( teta / 2.0 );
float q1 = qSin( teta / 2.0 ) * b.x();
float q2 = qSin( teta / 2.0 ) * b.y();
float q3 = qSin( teta / 2.0 ) * b.z();

QMatrix4x4 Q = QMatrix4x4(
            qPow(q0, 2) + qPow(q1, 2) - qPow(q2, 2) - qPow(q3, 2), 2 * ( q1 * q2 - q0 * q3 )                            , 2 * ( q1 * q3 + q0 * q2 )                            , 0,
            2 * ( q2 * q1 + q0 * q3 )                            , qPow(q0, 2) - qPow(q1, 2) + qPow(q2, 2) - qPow(q3, 2), 2 * ( q2 * q3 - q0 * q1 )                            , 0,
            2 * ( q3 * q1 - q0 * q2 )                            , 2 * ( q3 * q2 + q0 * q1 )                            , qPow(q0, 2) - qPow(q1, 2) - qPow(q2, 2) + qPow(q3, 2), 0,
            0                                                    , 0                                                    , 0                                                    , 0
            );

Q.transposed(); // Transpose is needed to be able to employ "Q" matrix with Qt3DCore::QTransform

Q.setColumn(3, QVector4D(QVector3D(18.2066, 38.2821, 42.5333), 1)); // Set translation/move to be equal to QVector3D(18.2066, 38.2821, 42.5333)
                                                         // In addition to rotation, we want to move/translate our cone too!
                                                         // https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/affine/matrix4x4/index.htm

Qt3DCore::QTransform *transform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();
transform->setMatrix(Q);
newEntity->addComponent(transform);
```

The original cone with its **default axis** and the transformed cone with its **new axis** are shown below:

[image: Original cone and transformed cone]